# agregar datos a struct c++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos, struct

esto es un pequeño fragmento de un sistema para un hospital, donde el usuario debe darse de alta ingresando los datos que se le solicitan. No puedo darme cuenta por que me tira errores. Lo que quiero lograr es que los datos ingresados por el usuario se guarden en los arreglos del struct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


#define MAX 5555556

//STRUCTS
struct paciente{
    string nombrepac[MAX];
    string apellido[MAX];
    int dni;
    int telefono;
}datos[MAX];

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].nombrepac;
    cout << "Ingrese su apellido: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].apellido;
    cout << "Ingrese su DNI: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].dni;
    cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].telefono;
}
    cout << "Presione ENTER para regresar al menu anterior. " << endl; getch(); system("cls"); 
}
```

muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿No crees que es exagerado tener 5555556 pacientes con 5555556 nombres y 5555556 apellidos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu estructura, lo que estás haciendo es que tengan una longitud máxima con la variable `MAX` para el nombre y apellido.

```
#define MAX 5555556 // <- definimos a "MAX" como resultado 5555556

//STRUCTS
struct paciente{
    string nombrepac[MAX]; // <- longitud de 5555556
    string apellido[MAX]; // <- longitud de 5555556
    int dni;
    int telefono;
}datos[MAX];
```

Ahora el problema vendría a ser en el `cin`, donde estás almacenando en los miembros del `struct` sin su longitud `[MAX]`, tendrías que pasar esto mismo en el miembro que tienen esta longitud:

```
cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].nombrepac[MAX];
cout << "Ingrese su apellido: " << endl; cin >> datos[i].apellido[MAX];
```

Ahora, entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es registrar los datos de varios pacientes para posteriormente listarlos. Mejorando un poco tu código resultaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

// STRUCTS
struct paciente
{
    string nombrepac;
    string apellido;
    int dni;
    int telefono;
};

paciente *datosPaciente = new paciente[MAX];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Registramos 3 pacientes
    {
        cout << "\nLista del paciente [" << i + 1 << "]:\n" << endl;

        cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl;
        cin >> datosPaciente[i].nombrepac;
        cout << "Ingrese su apellido: " << endl;
        cin >> datosPaciente[i].apellido;
        cout << "Ingrese su DNI: " << endl;
        cin >> datosPaciente[i].dni;
        cout << "Ingrese su numero de telefono: " << endl;
        cin >> datosPaciente[i].telefono;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // Listamos 3 pacientes
    {
        cout << "\nLos datos del paciente [" << i + 1 << "] es:\n" << endl;

        cout << "Nombres: " << datosPaciente[i].nombrepac << endl;
        cout << "Apellidos: " << datosPaciente[i].apellido << endl;
        cout << "DNI: " << datosPaciente[i].dni << endl;
        cout << "Celular: " << datosPaciente[i].telefono << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Presione ENTER para regresar al menu anterior. " << endl;
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Lista del paciente [1]:

// Ingrese su nombre:     
// Lucas
// Ingrese su apellido: 
// Soto
// Ingrese su DNI: 
// 123123   
// Ingrese su numero de telefono: 
// 123123123

// Lista del paciente [2]:

// Ingrese su nombre:     
// Pedro
// Ingrese su apellido: 
// Roman
// Ingrese su DNI: 
// 123123
// Ingrese su numero de telefono: 
// 123123123

// Lista del paciente [3]:

// Ingrese su nombre:
// Miguel
// Ingrese su apellido: 
// Julian
// Ingrese su DNI: 
// 123123
// Ingrese su numero de telefono: 
// 123123123

// Los datos del paciente [1] es:

// Nombres: Lucas
// Apellidos: Soto
// DNI: 123123
// Celular: 123123123


// Los datos del paciente [2] es:

// Nombres: Pedro
// Apellidos: Roman
// DNI: 123123
// Celular: 123123123


// Los datos del paciente [3] es:

// Nombres: Miguel
// Apellidos: Julian
// DNI: 123123
// Celular: 123123123
```

Comment: En realidad lo que hizo fue declarar dos arreglos de cadenas de caracteres. O sea, que cada paciente pueda tener 5555556 nombres y apellidos.

Comment: Probé con 3 pacientes, no voy a registrar 5555556 pacientes... además me parece un número exagerado, tendrá mucha carga de memoria.

Comment: El primer párrafo me da a entender que el struct contiene 2 strings de 5555556 caracteres. Quería saber si es eso lo que quieres decir.

Comment: Si, es justamente lo que decía.

Comment: `paciente *datosPaciente = new paciente[MAX];` pero al final definí la longitud máxima de esta forma, lo veo mejor